# Journals similar to Journal of Chemical Education in style

Tags: journals, education, online-resource

What are the journals similar to [*Journal of Chemical Education*](http://pubs.acs.org/page/jceda8/about.html) which are helpful from middle school through graduate school? I mean the journals which publish articles which are good resources for learning the basics (complementary to books).

[Note: The journals need not be necessarily in the field of Chemistry]

Comment: this is an open-ended list question, so I'm voting to close

Comment: @EnergyNumbers we have some great resources question that follow this format. And I don't think the list is going to cover more than a few resources, so it seem acceptable to me

Answer (score 3):

While I am a regular reader of *J. Chem. Ed.*, I wouldn't really say it's a good journal to read for learning the basics. It is more a journal of *educators in the field of chemistry*, and while I think some articles may be useful to chemistry students (including lab experiments and activities), overall its goal is to be a forum to discuss how we teach chemistry, rather than a place to *learn* chemistry.

For other journals about chemical education, you can find [a very short list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemistry_education#Academic_journals_on_chemistry_education). Also, as stated there, most such journals (especially for junior or high school chemical education) are localized, i.e. limited to a specific country (because of differences in curricula). Among the international ones, I would recommend *[Education in Chemistry](http://www.rsc.org/education/eic/)*, which is more readable than its sister journal *[Chemistry Education Research and Practice](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/journals/journalissues/rp#!recentarticles&all)*

Comment: Would you like to suggest some journals please ? :)